Additive real semigroups with an unbounded below part
Look at
$$(*)\;\;\; H=\{ m\sqrt{2}+k|m,k\in \mathbb{Z}, m\geq 2\}\cup (\mathbb{Z}_++\sqrt{2}).$$
It is obvious that $H$ is an additive sub-semigroup of real numbers. But, it is interesting to know that $H$ satisfies the following properties:
(1) $1+H\subset H$;
(2) there is $h_0\in H$ such that $h_0+\mathbb{Z}\subseteq H$.
Note that for every real semigroup $H$ satisfying (1) and (2), we have
$$
(3)\;\;\; \{h\in H: h+\mathbb{Z}\nsubseteq H\}\neq \emptyset.
$$
(Because $1+H\neq H$.)
It is worth noting that for the semigroup $(*)$ the set defined by (3) is bounded below.
Now, we are looking for an additive real semigroup $H$ satisfying (1), (2) such that the set defined by (3) is unbounded below (once $1\notin H$, and another time $1\in H$).
Is there such semigroup $H$?
Thanks in advance.

How about $(\mathbb{Z}_+ + \mathbb{Z}\sqrt{2}) \cup (\mathbb{Z} + \mathbb{Z}\sqrt{2} +\mathbb{Z}_+\sqrt{3})$?

A good example, thanks.
